# problems with implementing my own vector::emplace_back

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

**Background:**

I'm trying to implement std::vector myself. For now, I have only specialized version of it, which has MyStruct instances as an elements. The elements type has helper output like signalling how it was constructed (copy, move, value, default ctor). I added overload of operator<< to make it more convenient to debug. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 update 1.

**Problem:**

First of all, it seems like emplace_back call doesn't do what it is supposed to do. Trying to output back element it outputs trash. Additionally, when exiting scope of main(), there is error saying that the program tried to write into the memory outside of the heap. Added the image of the message box.

**EDIT:**

Push back with almost the same implementation of increasing capacity works. Added implementation and declaration as well.

Here is the code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "MyStruct.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "vector.h"

int main()
{
MyStruct ms(0);
Vector v;
v.emplace_back(2);

std::cout << v.back() << "\n";

std::system("pause");
}
```

**vector.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "MyStruct.h"

class Vector
{
    size_t mcapacity;
    MyStruct* mdata;
    size_t msize;
public:
    Vector();

    MyStruct& back();

    void push_back(const MyStruct& ms);

    template<typename ... ArgsType>
    void emplace_back(ArgsType ... args)
    {
        if (mcapacity == msize && msize == 0)
        {
            mdata = (MyStruct*)operator new[](sizeof(MyStruct));
            mcapacity++;
        }
        else if (mcapacity == msize)
        {
            MyStruct* tempdata = (MyStruct*)operator new[](sizeof(MyStruct) * mcapacity * 2);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < msize; i++)
            {
                new (tempdata + i) MyStruct(*(mdata + i));
            }
            mdata = tempdata;
            mcapacity *= 2;
        }
        new (mdata + msize) MyStruct(std::forward<ArgsType...>(args...));
        msize++;
    }

    ~Vector();
};
```

**vector.cpp**

```
#include "vector.h"
#include "MyStruct.h"
#include <iostream>

Vector::Vector() :
    mdata(nullptr), 
    msize(0), 
    mcapacity(0)
{

}

MyStruct& Vector::back()
{
    return *(mdata + msize - 1);
}

void Vector::push_back(const MyStruct& ms)
{
    if (mcapacity == msize && msize == 0)
    {
        mdata = (MyStruct*)operator new[](sizeof(MyStruct));
        mcapacity++;
    }
    else if (mcapacity == msize)
    {
        MyStruct* tempdata = (MyStruct*)operator new[](sizeof(MyStruct) * mcapacity * 2);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < msize; i++)
        {
            new (tempdata + i) MyStruct(*(mdata + i));
        }
        mdata = tempdata;
        mcapacity *= 2;
    }

    new (mdata + msize) MyStruct(ms);
    msize++;
}

Vector::~Vector()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < msize; i++)
    {
        (mdata + i)->~MyStruct();
    }

    operator delete[](mdata);//next statement to execute
}
```

Here is the error message box:
[image]

Output:

```
I'm constructed using value constructor
I'm constructed using value constructor
I'm printing the number -33686019!
```

This is MyStruct header and implementation, but I think none of functions throw any exceptions or invoke undefined behavior. Added all constructors since I was unsure which constructor is really called when invoking v.back(). Thought that compiler might did some optimizations. But according to output, value ctor was called.

**MyStruct.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iosfwd>

class MyStruct
{
    int x;
public:
    MyStruct();
    MyStruct(int x_);

    MyStruct(const MyStruct& other);

    MyStruct(MyStruct&& other) noexcept;

    void print(std::ostream& os) const;

    ~MyStruct();
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyStruct& ms);
```

**MyStruct.cpp**

```
#include "MyStruct.h"
#include <iostream>

MyStruct::MyStruct():
    x(0)
{
    std::cout << "I'm created using default constructor" << "\n";
}

MyStruct::MyStruct(MyStruct&& other) noexcept :
    x(other.x)
{
    std::cout << "I'm created using move constructor" << "\n";
}

MyStruct::MyStruct(const MyStruct& other):
    x(other.x)
{
    std::cout << "I'm created using copy constructor" << "\n";
}

MyStruct::~MyStruct()
{
    std::cout << "I'm destructed" << "\n";
}

void MyStruct::print(std::ostream& os) const
{
    os << "I'm printing the number " << x << "!\n";
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyStruct& ms)
{
    ms.print(os);
    return os;
}

MyStruct::MyStruct(int x_) :
    x(x_)
{
    std::cout << "I'm constructed using value constructor" << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I see memory leak but I cannot reproduce any error with gcc (except the missing back() in the class declaration).

Comment: @kukyakya, thank you, added declaration.

Comment: Suggest you change the title from std::vector so it reflects you are making your own version of a vector.

Comment: you probably want to change the formal argument to emplace_back to a forwarding reference since you're forwarding the pack inside the function.

Comment: `new (mdata + msize) MyStruct(std::forward<ArgsType...>(args...));` This wouldn't compile if you passed more than one argument; you're using `std::forward` wrong. It should be `std::forward<ArgsType>(args)...`.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I was confused by those ... . I was stumbling on it a lot of times. Could you please provide some rule or logic to follow when writing parameter pack expansion?

Comment: I ran the code with valgrind and duma, and got no error. What about changing `operator new[]()` to `operator new()`? `operator new[]()` usually calls `operator new()` but it could make an error if it doesn't, I guess.

Comment: @Kukyakya, tried, not really sure what should happen, but no changes.